# The Second Cohomology group with Coefficient in cyclic group of order 3.

Tags: group-theory, group-cohomology, p-groups

I am computing the second cohomology group $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z_3})$ of $G=$SmallGroup(81,9). Its presentation is given by
$G=\langle x,y,z\mid x^3=y^9=z^3=[y,z]=1,[y,x]=z,[z,x]=zy^3z^{-1}\rangle$.
I tried using the Consistency test ([Alexander Wegner's PhD Thesis](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cVInzD2b8axiGQEvVpmTZ7qQIOG_p7w7/view?usp=share_link), Theorem 2.7, page-23). From My calculations, I am getting $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z_3})\cong \langle (1,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,1,0)\rangle$. But Gap computations show that  $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z_3})\cong {\mathbb{Z_3}\times \mathbb{Z_3}\times \mathbb{Z_3}\times \mathbb{Z_3}}$.

Can Anyone help me where I am making a mistake? I have checked it many times. I am attaching a [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1812V1sRsjI6UeYCvWm0kRNaKxrhtsZl0/view?usp=share_link) to my Calculations.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Yes, I checked the presentation. You are right. Thank You